# How can i send gz compressed json response data using expressJS

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create an API using nodeJS, and i need the response to be gz compressed.

I use compression middleware in my code

app.use(compression());

and in my route

```
collection.find({_id: 'doc_id'}, reqField).toArray(function(err, docs) {
  if (err)
     res.send(err);
  var data = docs['vals'];
  JSON.stringify(data);
  res.send({status:301, response:data});
});
```

The response from this API is not compressed in the client side.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as i am new to nodeJS. Thanks in advance..

Comment: How are you checking the compression status of the response? Also, make sure that the middleware is included before any of your routes, and be aware that `compression` by default will not compress responses [smaller than 1kb](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#threshold).

Comment: In my response header it is showin that response type as text/html. . Also i put app.use(compression()); before routes.

Comment: The `Content-Type` will not change when compression is happening, you should look at the `Content-Encoding` header instead (this also assumes that the client you're using is setting the right `Accept-Encoding` header as well). Apart from that, `text/html` is strange because you're sending back JSON.

Comment: There is no Content-Encoding header int he response.  Connection 
close
Content-Length 
4837
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Wed, 17 Aug 2016 03:52:48 GMT
Server 
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.5.28;    This is the response header. In the request header there is  Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate

Comment: If you're using Node, why are the headers showing Apache + PHP?

Comment: I am using a cURL request to the node server from a PHP script and the header response header is :  HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 21491
ETag: W/"53f3-vdQz47lK52XS2pQ7v09u1g"
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 07:39:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121128/discussion-between-sumesh-p-and-robertklep).